# How to implement user mentions in React chat app without react-mentions and drafts-js library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highlight.js

I've implemented a user tag functionality while pressing @ and it's working fine.But i couldn't able to highlight the tagged user because i'm using input field..While using libraries like react-mentions and draft-js , I couldnt integrate them into the codebase because of some weird issues..Any idea of implementing the highlighting part in this code would be really helpful..Thanks..https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-pike-bzhzn?file=/src/AutoCompletedText.js

Comment: You can try to use div with `contenteditable` instead of `<input />`

Comment: Can you share any example code for implementing content editable div?

Comment: Here is a VERY START of using `contenteditable` https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-lovelace-pi03c?file=/src/AutoCompletedText.js. This approach is modifying the content of the div / input. Another approach (like react-mentions uses) is to hold a duplicate div [with the same text as the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u94hI.png) and highlight what needed there. Of course that there are edge cases that should be handled such scrolling.